# Getting all Users' scores using the Facebook Score API

Tags: javascript, facebook, json, api

Using the Scores section of the Facebook Graph API, is there a way to request the scores of all users?  Additionally, can they be requested sorted, ascending or descending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: No.

Long Answer: Under the Graph API, the `User` retains all `Application` data specific to their user account.  This may be for privacy reasons (to enable a user to confidently delete all of their application data at will, perhaps) or simply because Facebook has found that this relationship model is more efficient.  Whatever the reason, queries on the `Application` object can not be made to "get all Users".  Another way to look at it would be `User`--has-many-->`Application` and *not* `Application`--has-many-->`User`.

The workaround we are using involves querying for `User`-->`Friends`, caching the returned list of friend ID's, and then firing off individual `User`-->`Application Score` at each friend.  The upside is that it works, while the downsides are that it takes more time, wastes effort querying friends who either don't play our game or don't share their game data, and causes some of our users to bump up against Facebook's 600-in-600 queries-per-second limit.